# Class Definition Not Found Exception

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

```
 ClassDefNotFoundException: com/secure/api/Util/FieldsUtil
```

How to resolve this issue?

I am running application on Windows XP with Java installed in it.

Comment: Please provide you full stacktrace..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the API for this function.

You can set the class path after adding the API.

If you are using Netbeans or Eclipse, you can directly add the API jar to the projects.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using any external jar.

Find relevant jar for `FieldsUtil` class and set in your class path

Answer (score 0):

Just had to include JAR in project or should've had it in lib folder. Thank you. It works both way.